# UITableViewAutomaticDimension not setting correct height when there are emoji characters in the UILabel of UITableviewCell

Tags: uitableview, emoji

I am using UITableViewAutomaticDimension for dynamic height of cells of a UITableview. Everything works fine when I set plain text in the label inside the UITableviewCell.

Problem occurs with the cell height when I set plain text along with emoji characters in the label. The cell height do increase dynamically but the height is wrong due to emoji characters. I think UITableview may be considering the unicode as a text instead of emoji icon hence it returns only plain text height.

In my case label's x origin is also dynamic.

Please see the below screen shots for the problem occurring,
[image]

Any suggestions?